# Find all zeros of the equation $e^z = 1+2z$ in the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried solving the pair of equations 
\begin{align}
e^x\cos y&=1+2x\\
e^x\sin y&= 2y
\end{align}
but I got stuck.

Comment: I think this got something to do with Rouche's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: one solution is quite easy.  It also happens to be the only one.

Answer (score 0):

let $f(z) = e^{z}$ and $g(z) = -(1+2z)$ then on the boundary $e^{i\theta}$,

$$ |f(z)| = |e^{\cos \theta}| < \sqrt{5 + 4 \cos(\theta)} \tag{1}$$
Since $g(z)$ has  one root on $|z|<1$, by [Rouché's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) $f(z)+g(z)$ has one root on $|z|< 1 $. In particular, $z=0$ satisfies the equation and it is only the root of it as well.

To show that $(1)$ holds, one can simply show that $h(x) = e^x - \sqrt{5 + 4x}$ is smooth function on $[1,1]$ has $h(x)$ has [minimum value](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find%20minimum%20sqrt%285%20%2b%204%20x%29%20-e%5Ex%20on%20%20%28-1,%201%29) of $3-e$ on $x=1$.

Comment: How do you get $g(z)$?

Comment: @mattecapu i just constructed :)

Comment: $\lvert f(z)\rvert < \lvert g(z)\rvert$ on the boundary is not the condition you need. You could choose $g(z) \equiv 10$ and have that inequality. You need to bound $\lvert f(z)-g(z)\rvert$.

Comment: @DanielFischer hmm ... here in my book it is stated as "if $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic function on some region and $|f(z)|<|g(z)|$ on the boundary curve, then $f(z)$ and $f(z)+g(z)$ has same number of zeroes on the region R". Did I make any mistake somewhere?

Comment: Perhaps I could modify the $f(z)$ a bit ...

Comment: It says "$f(z)$ and $f(z)+g(z)$" have the same number of zeros, not "$f(z)$ and $g(z)$". But the condition should be $\lvert g(z)\rvert < \lvert f(z)\rvert$ on the boundary then, since $g = (f+g)-f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer does my new modification work?? are there still flaws?

Comment: You need a strict inequality in $(1)$. (You have the strict inequality in fact, but you wrote a weak inequality.)

Comment: @DanielFischer I hope it works now :S